# How to add metric and imperial system in wpf application

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

I have a default setting which states IsMetricMeasurements as a bool in settings as a default instance.But when I'am using it with CoerceProperty to check for max and min value and  make it metric even if user types and select inches . It is messing with the whole conversion system. Where should I put my logic of conversion i want to make mm (metric) .Even though if I check my xaml( IO file) it saves correct value but when I read the saved file in the application itself  it gives wrong values.

Dimensiondata.cs

```
public class DimensionData : BaseDateEntity, ICloneable, IDataErrorInfo ,IValueConverter

{

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DiameterProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Diameter", typeof(float), typeof(DimensionData),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Consts.DimensionDataDiameter, OnDiameterPropertyChanged, OnDiameterCoerceProperty));


    public float Diameter
    {
        get { return (float)GetValue(DiameterProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DiameterProperty, value); }
    }


 static object OnDiameterCoerceProperty(DependencyObject sender, object value)
   {              
       if (Properties.Settings.Default.IsMetricMeasurements)
         {      
            return RangeHelper.RangeLength(140F, 900F, (float)value);
          }
        else 
        {
           value = (float)value / 25.4F;
           return RangeHelper.RangeLength(5.511F, 35.43F, (float)value);               
        }

static void OnDiameterPropertyChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)

    {
        DimensionData data = dependencyObject as DimensionData;

        if (null != data)
        {

        }
    }
```

RangeHelper class

```
    public static float RangeLength(float min, float max, float value)
    {
        float r = value;

        if (r > max)
            r = max;

        if (r < min)
            r = min;
         return r;
```

Note: I have a toggle button that makes the text box into inches or mm by just selecting it. If i select mm  it works fine , But when I change to inches everything is messed up . Is there a place to add the logic of conversion(1 inch = 25.4mm) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working using Converter class and binding it , but still iam having few issues. Special thanks to @Ed Plunkett @EdPlunkett, he guided me in the right way.

Comment: Special thanks to t @EdPlunkett, he guided me in the right way.